Godot шаблон экспорта не устанавливается
Я разработчик игр на Godot решил выложить игру, пытаюсь в движке скачать шаблон экспорта и на 600 Мб выдаёт ошибку, что нет такого файла, пытаюсь с гитхаба скачать и тоже на 600 Мб прерывается и пишет Ошибка: Требуется авторизация. Пытался и в другом браузере, и другую версию, всё равно ошибка. Помогите пожалуйста.
Версия Godot 4.0.3

Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Я пытаюсь скачать шаблон экспорта, а он на середине останавливается и пишет файл недоступен на сайте. Возобновить установку нельзя, в решениях пишет проверить соединение или попробовать скачать позже, но я уже 2 дня пытаюсь скачать.
